# Python character and word counts

Tags: python, string, count, character, counter

I'm a beginner with python and would like to know how to use two txt files to count the characters as well as counter the 10 most common characters. also how to convert all characters in the file to lower case and eliminate all characters other than a-z

here's what i've tried and had no luck with:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

with open ('document1.txt' , 'document2.txt') as f:
    print Counter(letter for line in f
                    for letter in line.lower()
                    if letter in ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving, also your with statement is not the right format. With open("file.txt", "r") as data: you can't open two files with the same with statement. You need two with statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example.  You can adapt this code to fit your needs

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1data: #opening an reading file one
    file1 = file1data.read().lower() #convert the entire file contents to lower

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2data: #opening an reading file two
    file2 = file2data.read().lower() 

#The contents of both file 1 and 2 are stored in fil1 and file2 variables
#Examples of how to work with one file repeat for two files
file1_list = []
for ch in file1:
    if ch in ascii_lowercase: #makes sure only lowercase alphabet is appended.  All Non alphabet characters are removed
        file1_list.append(ch)
    elif ch in [" ", ".", ",", "'"]: #remove this elif block is you just want the letters
        file1_list.append(ch) #make sure basic punctionation is kept

print "".join(file1_list) #this line is not needed. Just to show what the text looks like now
print Counter(file1_list).most_common(10) #prints the top ten
print Counter(file1_list) #prints the number of characters and how many times they repeat
```

Now that you've reviewed that mess above and have an idea of what each line is doing, here is a cleaner version, that does what you were looking for.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1data: 
    file1 = file1data.read().lower()

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2data: 
    file2 = file2data.read().lower() 

file1_list = []
for ch in file1:
    if ch in ascii_lowercase: 
        file1_list.append(ch)

file2_list = []
for ch in file2:
    if ch in ascii_lowercase: 
        file2_list.append(ch)



all_counter = Counter(file1_list + file2_list) 
top_ten_counter = Counter(file1_list + file2_list).most_common(10) 

print sorted(all_counter.items()) 
print sorted(top_ten_counter)
```

Comment: Thanks. This did work, but it's pulling up the entire file. how do i get it to only show the counter? also how do i get it to show like:
a 20
b 10
c 14
etc 
rather than
a 20 b 10 c 14

Comment: Made edits to the above code that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import re
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', "{} {}".format(open('your_file1').read().lower(), open('your_file2').read().lower()))
>>> Counter(words).most_common(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to insert into the middle of a file without re-writing it. As previous posters have indicated, you can append to a file or overwrite part of it using seek but if you want to add stuff at the beginning or the middle, you'll have to rewrite it.

This is an operating system thing, not a Python thing. It is the same in all languages.

What I usually do is read from the file, make the modifications and write it out to a new file called myfile.txt.tmp or something like that. This is better than reading the whole file into memory because the file may be too large for that. Once the temporary file is completed, I rename it the same as the original file.

This is a good, safe way to do it because if the file write crashes or aborts for any reason, you still have your untouched original file.

To find most common `words` from multiple files,

```
from collections import Counter
import re
with open(''document1.txt'') as f1, open(''document1.txt'') as f2:
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', f1.read().lower()) + re.findall(r'\w+', f2.read().lower())
    >>>Counter(words).most_common(10)
    "wil give you most 10 common words"
```

If you want most 10 common `characters`

```
>>>Counter(f1.read() + f2.read()).most_common(10)
```